# CSS isn't rendered on a post but just posted as text

Tags: css

I have a wordpress.com hosted blog at sergiotapiag.wordpress.com and I can't seem to get my code to be published with my required setting. Wordpress is not rendering my embedded stylesheet but displaying it's contents. I'm using Windows Live Writer 2011 and the Insert Code plugin to format the code.

Any ideas on how to tell wordpress to RENDER the html/css i post and not just escape it as text?

Comment: @Serg - If you get a *self-hosted* WordPress website you can do absolutely anything you want with it. The limitation you are experiencing is only with the free hosted WordPress.com account. See: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/self-hosted-wordpress-org-vs-free-wordpress-com-infograph/

Answer (score 1):

Custom CSS is available as [a premium upgrade on WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-css/), so style information is probably filtered out of posts you create with other tools.

Comment: What other blog platform do you recommend that does allow me to post whatever I want?

Comment: @Serg: You mean alternative WordPress hosts? Or alternative blogging systems?

Comment: Alt bloggin systems that let me upload code in nice format?